# remove decimal from number and convert to 12 digit

Tags: php

how to convert number(price) from `1.00`  to  `000000000100`  total all string must `12 digits`
if price `100.00` so function should convert to `000000010000` same if price `150.00` function should convert to `000000015000` .

this value actually i need to send to bank(payment gateway) for process.

Thanks if you can help me on this .

Comment: What type is `1.00`? PS: see `str_pad()`

Comment: integer cannot contain fraction part. `1.00` cannot be integer, `1` - can be

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, proper sentences with interpunction would be better readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a function to do that:

```
/**
 * Format a price according to the bank payment gateway specification.
 *
 * @param $price float The price
 * @return The formatted price
 */
function format_price($price) {
    $price = (int) ($price * 100);
    return str_pad((string) $price, 12, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
$num=<number with 2 decimal places>;
$strnum=''.intval($num*100);
while(strlen($strnum)<12)
    $strnum='0'.$strnum;
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer for those who came to php dev from c dev:)

```
$a = 100.00;
printf("a=%012d", $a*100);
```

output: a=000000010000

```
$a = 150.00;
printf("a=%012d", $a*100);
```

output: a=000000015000

For number conversion need to use `sprintf`:

```
$a = 150.00;
$b = sprintf("%012d", $a*100);
var_dump($b);
```

output: string(12) "000000015000"